# What's the accepted way to write a C# TSR?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using C# to write a WCF router which I want to stay running without using the Console.ReadKey "hack".  I was wondering if there's an accepted way to do this within C# that's more elegant than

```
while (true)
    Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Comment: Heh a bit of a dilemma. The ManualResetEvent answer is closest to want I actually want and is what I will probably use, but the Windows Service is the better answer to how my question is phrased and for general usage so it gets the accepted tick. Thanks guys, both great answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a `windows service` project. windows services have persistent lifecycle as compared to standard windows client.

You can get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(VS.80).aspx).

From msdn:

After the service has been loaded, it must be started. Starting the service allows it to begin functioning. You can start a service from the Services Control Manager, from Server Explorer, or from code by calling the Start method. The Start method passes processing to the application's OnStart method and processes any code you have defined there.

`A running service can exist in this state indefinitely until it is either stopped or paused or until the computer shuts down.` A service can exist in one of **three basic states: Running, Paused, or Stopped**. You can query the Status to determine what state a service is in.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a ManualResetEvent?

```
ManualResetEvent stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void StartService()
{

     service.Open();
     stopEvent.WaitOne()
}
```

You can then do a stopEvent.Set() when you want the service to terminate.